# Add admob in app error

Tags: android, admob

I try add admob Ads in my app. Initial I add code :

```html
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("abc")
            .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

but it not run, it show error

```html
11-23 11:16:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 11:16:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(24361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.phohaycom/com.example.phohay.activity.ReadingActivity2}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
```

So I try add code :

```html
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
  mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
  mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1845170371498416/12345678");
  
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("D5AF9D9AFD269EF3B817CD9804BF2CE9")
        .build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

It run but when I run it, it not show Ads which only displays text "Either XML attribute "ad Size" or XML attribute "supported Ad Sizes" should be specified, but not both.
My xml file :

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

it fails anywhere? Please help me

Comment: Have you called `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`

Comment: have you set up your ad properly through admob account

Comment: I get the ID from my boss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it. 
I don't add code in xml. Instead I create Linear Layout and add Ads in code

```html
AdView adView = new AdView(getApplication());
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1845170371498416/123456789");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

         LinearLayout adLinLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Llayout);
        adLinLay.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
    "D5AF9D9AFD269EF3B817CD9804BF2CE9").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Thank everyone! good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think remove either of `ads:adSize="BANNER"` or `mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);` will help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one ? :

**Remove** this one:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

**Delete** the xmlns:ads*** tag

**Add** this one:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

xml file should looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you, but i try it before asked my question, it not run with me.

Comment: yes, I see tutorial and try but if I add AdView in XML it not run, I try add in code it run.